# W3C validation error: span element

Tags: html, validation

When I validate my page I have the following error:

> Element span not allowed as child of element ul in this context.
>   (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

This is my HTML markup:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="nav-home">
        <a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
    <li class="nav-paints">
        <a href="paints.html" title="Paints">Paints</a>
    </li>
    <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
    <li class="nav-non-paints">
        <a href="non-paints.html" title="Non-paints" class="active">Non-paints</a>
    </li>
    <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
    <li class="nav-advies">
        <a href="advies.html" title="Advies">Advies</a>
    </li>
    <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
    <li class="nav-training">
        <a href="training.html" title="Training">Training</a>
    </li>
    <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
    <li class="nav-afvalbeheer">
        <a href="afvalbeheer.html" title="Afvalbeheer">Afvalbeheer</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I tried replacing the spans by regular divs and put them on inline, however, this is apparently also not allowed. Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The only valid children of `ul` or `ol` elements _are_ `li` elements. You can put a `span` or a `div` inside a `ul` or `ol`, but only if they're enclosed in a `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `<span>` element is not nested in any other tag and in any level, because you are putting the `<span>` element within a list but out of any `<li>` element. So the list is breaking out!

Try putting it inside any element, inside `<li>` element if you can, for example!

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="nav-home">
        <a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a>
        <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-paints">
        <a href="paints.html" title="Paints">Paints</a>
    </li>
    <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
    <li class="nav-non-paints">
        <a href="non-paints.html" title="Non-paints" class="active">Non-paints</a>
        <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-advies">
        <a href="advies.html" title="Advies">Advies</a>
        <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-training">
        <a href="training.html" title="Training">Training</a>
        <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-afvalbeheer">
        <a href="afvalbeheer.html" title="Afvalbeheer">Afvalbeheer</a>
        <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm using these spans as a divider-like element to separate my navigation items. So if I just put the spans in <li> elements like you said, would that be semantically correct?

Comment: Well, semantic web is more about using correct semantic elements (article, section... instead of div, for example) more than put a divider-like element inside the same tag of the Menu item itself. What is clear is that put the span element out of the <li> element is not technically correct and is non-compliant with the W3C. So I think the better solution is to put the divider-like element inside another one.

By the way, here you have a good [link](http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/) article about Semantic Web

Comment: The `span` elements *are* nested in another element (the `ul` element), just improperly nested.

Comment: Yes @JukkaK.Korpela, you are totally right, I have explained badly! I would say that is not nested in the correct element

Answer (score 2):

You should place the `span` inside the `li`, like this:

```
<li class="nav-home">
    <a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a>
    <span class="solidus"> &#47;</span>
</li>
```

This is completely valid.